# Force require client certificate in tomcat context

Tags: tomcat, ssl, web.xml

After searching several hours on Google/StackOverflow, I've come to conclude nobody has a solid working top-to-bottom answer for this, so I'm going to try and ask it again.

I need a specific web application to force the use of client certificates (and I really mean FORCE).
My tomcat connector is described as (note the use of the Apr configuration variables):

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           SSLEngine="on"
           SSLCertificateFile="conf/server.crt"
           SSLCertificateKeyFile="conf/server.key"
           SSLPassword="password"
           SSLCACertificateFile="conf/ca.crt"
           SSLVerifyClient="none"
            />
```

I have made a simple webapplication with a single page, with this web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="...">
    <display-name>Security</display-name>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>ClientCertificateRequired</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>any</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <description/>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

So far, so good. If I request the page using a webbrowser, I am asked to choose a certificate. All this seems pretty good.

I realized I had a problem, when I clicked cancel! The page simply shows up. This is NOT what I had expected.

After more testing, I came to realize that tomcat might be trying to authenticate the certificate as a user (which it tried when I added a role requirement). This is unusuable, as the sheer amount of client certificates can't be registered dynamically in tomcat-users.xml.

Can anybody please explain what I am doing wrong here?

I want this web context to force require a client certificate BEFORE showing any content, whilst allowing other contexts to exclude the requirements. Preferably without resorting to custom servlets to perform additional server-side validation.

With the utmost kind regards,
Rory

Answer (score 0):

In server.xml Connector section, try to set SSLVerifyClient to `optional` (like wantClientAuth in Java) or `require` (needClientAuth). This SSL switch is controlled by tcnative (openssl) but not tomcat (catalina) itself.

see: http://www.modssl.org/docs/2.1/ssl_reference.html#ToC13

btw, enable SSL by Http11NioProtocol (tomcat uses JSSE implementation) is also not a bad choise.

Comment: Selecting 'none' or 'optional' makes no difference. By clicking cancel, I still get the page content. Using 'require' makes it required for all contexts, which is not what i really want. It is however, the only solution that actually does what it needs to do.

Comment: This can get client certs: `X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");`. Just response 403 or warning pages if certs == null.

Answer (score 0):

All what you need to do is to change the attribute SSLVerifyClient of your connector to required

(N.B. SSLVerifyClient is an alias of certificateVerification, you can check Apache Tomcat doc. [Here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html))

Your connector must look like

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
       maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
       SSLEngine="on"
       SSLCertificateFile="conf/server.crt"
       SSLCertificateKeyFile="conf/server.key"
       SSLPassword="password"
       SSLCACertificateFile="conf/ca.crt"
       SSLVerifyClient="required"
        />
```